# How do i read the opensearch nodes in lastfm results

Tags: php, xml, api, last.fm

I am working with the lastfm api and i want to be able to paginate the search results from the artist search.

```
<results xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" for="cher">
<opensearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="cher" startPage="1"/>
<opensearch:totalResults>1302</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>30</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
```

I would guess that it would involve taking the totalresults node and dividing it by the items per page. but how do i get the info from totalresults using php?

if this `$artists = $xml->results->artistmatches->artist;` is how i get the artists, how do i get the correct opensearch node totalresults and items per page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use simpleXML:

```php
$total = (int) $xml->results->children("http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/")->totalResults
```